# How to add a plot to a Figure in matplotlib?

Tags: django, matplotlib

i'm using matplotlib with django. I'm trying to create bar charts.

i followed the [cookbook](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Django), but i just got a grey rectangular box.

Now I'm using the following code, and have a title and axes.

How can I add a bar graph to the figure? Currently there is no actual data inside the axes.

Here's my charting code:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg 
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Chart(object):

    ## Creates a bar chart of the given data
    @staticmethod
    def bar(data):
        figure = Figure(figsize=(6,6))
        ax = figure.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
        labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
        fracs = [15, 30, 45, 10]
        explode=(0, 0.05, 0, 0)
        plt.pie(fracs, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True)
        figure.suptitle('Raining Hogs and Dogs', fontsize=14)

        canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(figure)

        return canvas
```

In my view I have:

```
canvas = Chart.bar(results)

# turn the returned canvas into an HTTP response
response=HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
canvas.print_png(response)
return response
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    fig = Figure()
    fig = Figure(facecolor='white', edgecolor='white')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

    x = matplotlib.numpy.arange(0, len(dic.keys()))

    ind = matplotlib.numpy.arange(len(dic.values()))

    height = 0.8
    ax.bar(ind, dic.values(), width, color=colors)

    ax.set_xticks(ind + width / 2.0)
    ax.set_xticklabels(dic.keys())

    padding = 0.2
    ax.set_xlim([x.min() - padding, x.max() + width + padding])

    canvas =  FigureCanvas(fig)
    response = django.http.HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    fig.savefig(filename)
```

this will create a bar graph, and save the image. Just have to call the function into your views. and open the image in the template. I passed a dictionary to this function(dic) but you can pass a list, is up to you.

in this case the keys are the x axis and the values are the y axis.